# new to using the autocomplete with jquery

Tags: json, jquery-autocomplete

I am using the mvc pattern to pull in an autocomplete. I have searched around and apologize if this is a repeat question but I couldnt find my exact case which technically is very straighforward.

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
        source: "remote_bookmark.php?f=autocomplete",
        minLength: 3,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.a.val;
        ui.b.val;
        ui.c.val;
        ui.d.val;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

this calls the remote page which calls a sql query in the model. The information is put into a multidimensional array that looks like the following in the model:

```
 array_push($bookmark_array, array($row['a'],$row['b'], $row['c'], $row['d'], $row['e']));
```

I then echo the json_encode in the remote and after looking at the documentation still dont seem to follow how I am supposed to put the information in the select:

Comment: jQuery UI Autocomplete 1.8.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
    source: "remote_bookmark.php?f=autocomplete",
    minLength: 3
});
```

You do not need a select function unless you want to add extra functionality that is npt already there.

Just change your php to:

```
$bookmark_array = array($row['a'],$row['b'], $row['c'], $row['d'], $row['e']);
echo json_encode($bookmark_array);
```

And you should be all fine and dandy :-)

Comment: so in theory it should work with the removal of the select function or do i need to somehow reorganize the information?

Comment: ah i had to change my format to be name value so it would process correctly. Was getting messed up in my multidimensional array. good stuff